# Flask - How can I reuse the URL parameters replacing function?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to build a view class that automatically builds the redirect url based on a string, for example :

```
class DeleteBook(RedirectView):
    route = "/library/<int:library_id>/book/<int:book_id>/delete"
    redirect_url = "/library/<int:library_id>/book"

    def context(self, library_id, book_id):
        book = Book(book_id)
        book.delete()
```

And `RedirectView` (please consider that `BaseView` is unimportant for the question)

```
class RedirectView(BaseView):

    def replace_parameters(self, url, **params):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def get(self, **params):
        try:
            self.context(**params)
            flash('Book deleted')
        except:
            flash('Could not delete book')
        finally:
            redirect_url = self.replace_parameters(self.redirect_url, params)
            return redirect(redirect_url)
```

How can I implement `replace_parameters` in my `RedirectView` class so that it behaves exactly like Flask's route parameter replacing function?

This question I think is mostly related to knowing the Flask internal API, I couldn't find the method that does this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for something similar to `url_for`. This function behaves a little bit different from the implementation you are looking for in that it expects the function name of the route you are trying to replace the url for but it might give you some ideas on how it is done. Here is the link to the [source code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/helpers.py#L226) . From the looks of it this call builds the url on line 357.

`rv = url_adapter.build(endpoint, values, method=method, force_external=external)`

It looks like the `url_adapter` is derived from either the application or request context which means you might be able to use the adapter in your `RedirectView` class to avoid coding the functionality again.

Answer (score 2):

Using `url_for` would be the most Flasky thing to do. The aim of using it is decoupling your code from the URLs, you just reference the view/route name.
In the specific case you share it would look something like this:

```py
class DeleteBook(RedirectView):
    route = "/library/<int:library_id>/book/<int:book_id>/delete"
    redirect_route = 'library_books'

    def context(self, library_id, book_id):
        book = Book(book_id)
        book.delete()


class RedirectView(BaseView):

    def get(self, **params):
        try:
            self.context(**params)
            flash('Book deleted')
        except:
            flash('Could not delete book')
        finally:
            return redirect(url_for(redirect_view, params))
```

`library_books` would be the name of the view that handles the url '/library//book'.

[Here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) is the API reference doc of `url_for`. It can handle keywords params with names of the path variables.